# QGIS 3.22.11: How can I attach different species to one polygon in a polygon layer

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, excel

I have a polygon-layer with several polygons, and I have an excel-table with many detected species in some of these polygons. I want to attach all the species that belong to polygon 1 to polygon 1, and all the species that belong to polygon 2 should be attached to polygon 2. [image]

So first I have a shapefile with 3 different polygons, in the screenshot you see an example for the excel table, and in the end I want to have 6 polygons, every polygon with the information, which species were found there.

I have tried to attribute join the excel data to the shapefile
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q6yVNcpnD8I)
but then only the first species belonging for example to the polygon 1 is shown in the result attribut table.

But I want all three species that were found in polygon 1. What can I do?

My next step to create a 1-n-relation
[image]

here comes the screenshot of the solution from the toolbox "Join Attributes by Field Value"[image]

Comment: What you are looking for is a 1-n relation : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?highlight=relation#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I could create the 1-n-relation like visible above. All species are indicated in the formular. But how can I create a new shapefile, that contains all species in all polygons? The export of the original shapefile did not give the result I am looking for.

Comment: Could you expend on what are the result you are looking, in witch way all species should be contain in a polygon ?

Comment: I want to create a shapefile with all polygons and all species, the attribute table of the shapefile should look like my example above of the excel table.

Comment: If the attribute table look like your exemple excel file that mean that you will have duplicate polygon, each polygon referencing one species, on top of each other is that your goal ?

Comment: How does the excel file look like, can you add a screenshot of it?

Comment: Could you prepare your tabular data first, perhaps using a power query to create text delimited values of your species for each polygon, and then join that to your spatial polygons?  See https://superuser.com/questions/453041/grouping-labels-and-concatenating-their-text-values-like-a-pivot-table.   Another approach might be to join your polygons to your tabular data creating a poly for each and then using a tool, perhaps aggregate to concatenate species.  I thought there was a dissolve tool to do that but didn't find it quickly.

Comment: @J.R: yes, that is what I want to have

Comment: @BERA  like the first screenshot above

Comment: look here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361259/many-to-one-relationship-or-join-in-qgis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found the solution: I use the tool in the toolbox: "Join Attributes by Field Value" - see the 3. screenshot above. "Wildbienen" is the shapefile - "1Artenlisten" is the excel-table I put to the QGIS-project (csv-Format), and in both I choosed the columns, that fit together. And then - very important + I choose the option "Create separate feature for each matching feature (one-to-many)". Then "run" . Then everything works, I get a new shapefile with together 146 objects (different species in 8 polygons).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Virtual Layer:

```sql
select a.*, b.species from polygon123 a
left join "Sheet1" b
on a."no" = b."polygon no"
```

Add the shapefile and excel to the map then Layer - Add Layer - A virtual layer. Change the layer- and fieldnames in the query to match your data.

Polygon 1 is duplicated three times since I have three species in the excel:

[image]